# How to put a vertical line above a number?

Tags: symbols

I need help about how to put vertical line above number ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your question is completely unclear! Which number? Which documentclass?

Comment: Close-Voters: Give some time to improve the question ;-

Comment: Do you mean something like a `\bar{}` rotated 90 degrees? @Christian Hupfer Isn't that what the on hold feature is for?

Comment: \documentclass{article}

Comment: I need something simmilar to  \'4 but with vertical line above 4

Comment: (I'm, sorry,I have poor knowledge of using latex..)

Comment: @Monika can you add a picture of what you want to your question (you can edit your question to add it)? Does the “vertical line” you want mean something? (And if yes: what does it mean?)

Comment: @JJMDriessen: Well, I would say no. We close and put on the old if the question is at least one day old and is unclear and has not been improved. After a few minutes closing is too early since there's some chance that I might be improved. Putting it on the Hold stake and improving and casting the reopen line takes time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb} % required for \shortmid
\usepackage{stackengine}

\newcommand{\vbar}[1]{\stackon[1pt]{$#1$}{\shortmid}} % vbar = vertical bar

\begin{document}

Like this? \vbar{5}

\end{document}
```

[image]